# Playframework: play.data.Form<T>.fill(T value) doesn't populate the form

Tags: playframework

I am using Playframework 2.8.x and I want to fill a play.data.Form in my controller and pass the filled copy to the frontend, where I want to use it in a view template to pre-fill a form with the saved values (for editing).
However, the [fill-Method](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/java/play/data/Form.html#fill-T-) which - as I understand it - should return a COPY of the form, that has been filled with the passed objects fields as values, does not get populated. Any pointers on that?

Here's some example code:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

private Form<User> userForm;
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("controllers.Application");


@Inject 
public HomeController(FormFactory formFactory, MessagesApi messagesApi) {
    this.userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);
    this.messagesApi = messagesApi;
}

public Result editProfile(Request request) {
    
    User activeUser = User.find.query().where().eq("email", "example@test.de").findOne();
    logger.info("User - Firstname: " + activeUser.getFirstName());
    userForm = userForm.fill(activeUser);

    logger.info("userForm - raw data: " + userForm.rawData());
    logger.info("userForm: " + userForm);
    
    return ok(editProfile.render(userForm, request, messagesApi.preferred(request)));
}
}
```

The user is successfully retrieved from the database (the first log writes the correct name to the console, while the second and third logs show that the form is indeed empty:

```
userForm - raw data: {}
userForm: Form(of=class models.User, data={}, value=Optional[User [email= example@test.de]], errors=[])
```

Why doesn't the form get populated?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The form actually got populated all the time. It just doesn't carry any "raw" data. The form's value is of class Optional and can be retrieved in the frontend like this:

```
@userForm.value().get().getEmail()
```

Where userForm.value() gets you the Optional, the get() gets you the actual User and the getEmail() is my getter method for the field email on the Model User.